# drill holes at specified offsets

Tags: modeling

How can I add holes at specific offsets from the edges of my object (as per picture below)? Using edge loops, I believe I can measure from the middle of the object, but it would be much easier to measure from the edges. Is that possible? Tks!

[image]

Answer (score 2):

All sorts of ways, making your own measuring sticks, temporary edges or loose vertices to snap to, etc, etc, but here's an example for putting holes in a tube at measured Z positions using the cursor...

- Make a section with a hole, and in edit mode with all selected,
  <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>S</kbd> > 'Cursor to Selected':

[image]

- <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>D</kbd> duplicate the section.
- In the Properties Region, 3D Cursor panel, set the Cursor to the desired Z
- The duplicate section should be selected...  <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>S</kbd> again > 'Selection to Cursor (Offset)

[image]

- Rinse, repeat ...
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>E</kbd> > 'Bridge Edge Loops' to fill the gaps

[image]

If you mean from other edges, you can place the cursor at the median of *any* selection of elements in Edit Mode, and you can enter arithmetic expressions in its location fields.. so if the cursor was at, say, 1.414, you can just add a "-0.5" to the end of the existing value to get your offset.

Comment: Many thanks. That's very helpful. In my case, picking up on your earlier suggestion, I greated a loose vertex, made the vertex a parent of an array of cylinders, and then through a boolean operation, used the cylinder to make holes in my cube object.

Comment: @Crowdpleasr   There you go.. I wouldn't have thought of that.. I would usually use an Empty that way... and that reminds me, I forgot to mention Delta Transforms in the Object tab.. so many ways ...